# Operador modulo (%) no funciona en reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quiero hacer un calculo matematico para hacer un componente que coloque ciertos iconos de estrellas segun el rate pasado por propiedades.

en el render tengo:

```
render() {
  let {rate} = this.props
  return (
    <div>
      {this.getStars(rate) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

y mi funcion getStars es la siguiente:

```
getStars(rate){
  let items = []
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    (
      items.push(
        <div className="star" key={i}>
          { rate * 2 > i && i % 2 && (
            <i className="fas fa-star"></i>
          )}
        </div>
      )
    )
  }

  return items;
}
```

El problema ocurre aqui cuando uso `i % 2`:

```
{ rate * 2 > i && i % 2 && (
  <i className="fas fa-star"></i>
)}
```

Asi como está `i % 2` rederiza un 0, literal

Coloco la condicion al inicio del for algo como:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  let isValidStar = rate * 2 > i && i % 2
  (
    items.push(
      <div className="star" key={i}>
        { isValidStar && (
          <i className="fas fa-star"></i>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  )
}
```

y me sale un error: `Uncaught TypeError: 2 is not a function`

El modulo (%) es el que me está dando el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parte del problema es el operador && en React, que se comporta de un modo distinto cuando la condición es `false` y cuando es un valor "falso", como `0`. Eso unido a que tienes 2 operadores &&, te crea ese problema:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.test = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.test=1; //pasamos a un valor "verdadero"
      this.forceUpdate();
    },2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.test && <p>Esto es un test :)</p>}</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

class App2 extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.test = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.test = true; //trabajando con booleanos todo el tiempo
      this.forceUpdate();
    },2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.test && <p>Esto es otro test :)</p>}</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App2 />, document.getElementById('root2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<div id="root2"></div>
```

Te recomiendo hacer algo como añadir una doble negación para forzar que el valor comprobado sea un booleano: `!!(cond)`

Answer (score 2):

El paréntesis que engloba a `items.push` está de más. En el fondo es como si estuvieses pasando como parámetro a una función `2` el resultado de `items.push`. Algo como:

```js
2('lo que sea')
```

La manera correcta sería:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let isValidStar = rate * 2 > i && i % 2;
    items.push(
      <div className="star" key={i}>
        {isValidStar && <i className="fas fa-star" />}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Es curioso que `0 && elemento` muestre 0, pero `1 && elemento` muestre el elemento... supongo que es mejor trabajar sólo con booleanos en este caso